# Switching to Parallel.For (from a sequencial for)

Tags: c#, for-loop, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm changing my code to use a `Parallel.For` instead of a simple `for` statement. My code have 3 nested `for` to make a comparison pixel-by-pixel of two images.

In the last `for` I save the cut points (TopLeft and BottomRight) where the image should be cut to reduce the filesize.

```
//For the 1st way:
int firstY = listBit[index].Height; //starts from the end.
int firstX = listBit[index].Width;
int lastY = 0; int lastX = 0;
//For the 2nd way:
var valueX = new List<int>();
var valueY = new List<int>();
//For the 3rd way:
var startY = new bool[listBit[index].Height];
var startX = new bool[listBit[index].Width];

//x - width - sides
Parallel.For(0, width, x =>
{
     //y - height - up/down
     for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
         //image1 and image2 are bitmaps (inside a help class).
         if (image1.GetPixel(x, y) == image2.GetPixel(x, y))
         {
             image2.SetPixel(x, y, transparent);
         }
         else
         {
             //Here i save the cut points, to crop the image later.

             //Old way: (compare and store in a variable)
             if (x < firstX)
             {
                 firstX = x;
             } //here was the rest of it, works only with a sequencial loop.

             //2nd way: (store in a list all entries, the List<> will blow, eventually)
             valueX.Add(x);
             valueY.Add(y); //and later use LINQ to get the values (first and last).

             //3rd way: (store a flag for each pixel, works)
             startX[x] = true;
             startY[y] = true;
             //but how can I get the first and last values==true of this array?

             //Any other idea?
         }
     }
 });
```

**Any better way of getting the cut points?**

Comment: I would compare the two implementations you suggested. It's not a given that parallel foreach has better performance. For small loops the overhead of managing threads may reduce performance.

Comment: Even for 1000x1000 x images?

Comment: However, for large images you will probably see a benefit from parallel processing. It depends on your hardware too though and how many threads you can run concurrently. I would just time it to see the difference

Comment: Small image: first Parallel, later Sequencial:

`00:00:00.0469242`
`00:00:00.0155887`

Comment: Big image (1000x500): Parallel, Sequencial:

`00:00:00.0780687`
`00:00:00.1718773`